# User Profile Service: Published, connected but doesn't seem to work

Tags: 2013, 2016, ups

I have managed to publish a User Profile Service (UPS) on a 2016 farm which I will call Publisher2016, and connected to a 2013 farm, say Consumer2013.Both farms are in same domain.

The setting up process completed without any errors. The connection is there and selected in Web Application's Service connections. However when I click on a user name, in consumer2013, it just takes me to user properties, which doesn't seem to be updated with the sync. (which is working perfectly fine on publisher2016)

Also, When I am on Central Admin on Consumer2013, I can see, 'About me'under the username on top right corner, however on the web application that I want this to work doesn't have that but have 'My Settings' instead- which makes me think it is not connected to UPS properly.

With no errors in log, I am really stuck on what to do, where to investigate. I tried deleting one user from a site collection (using the hidden user list) hoping it might re-populate the correct information but no luck.

Please could someone advise, where can I start investigating this? All search attempts got me to dead end as they seem to offer changing configuration assuming the farm hosts UPS itself, where else in my case farm consumes from another farm.

Comment: What patch level are you running? There have been improvements in publishing of the UPSA to consumer farms within the past couple of patches.

Comment: when I check in CA it says version -16.0.4351.1000

Comment: That's the RTM build number. I'd suggest you deploy the October 2017 PU. You need to deploy both for each month; sts-x-none (https://support.microsoft.com/help/4011217) and wssloc (https://support.microsoft.com/help/4011161). Microsoft's strong recommendation is that you deploy PUs as soon as possible on a monthly basis for SharePoint 2016.

Comment: I'll deploy the patches and let you know. Thanks Trevor

Comment: did you added the App pool account from Consumer farm into User Profile with full rights?

Comment: please reply this as an answer so I can mark it. Thank you so much. I am surprised it didn't error when it connected.